# C# Win Form Application UI Slow when Timer for Updates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.timers.timer

I've written a C# Windows Form application that gets data from a network device and displays the data to the main form.
I am using a timer and it calls functions that get the data from the unit and then updates the data on the main form. My application is slowing down while the timer getting/displaying the data runs.

I'm guessing that the timer is running in the UI thread?? What would be a good way to solve this issue and make my application more responsive while getting/displaying data?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: OK, I figured it would need to be in another task. Do I need to call the task from the timer tick?